# JAVA JDBC issues with List Return

Tags: java, android, jdbc

Longtime lurker. I have been working in Java trying to execute this JDBC SQL statement I have and can sometimes get results running class as a static void. When I attempt to make result set into a list and return it I get the error log attached at bottom. I apologize before hand if I didn't post something correctly. Odds are I am missing something but can't seem to get my eyes to notice it.

Thanks in advance

P.S. Be gentle it's my first time.

Beadsssss

//////////////////Main Activity that calls SQL Event/////////////////////////

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    int SDK_INT = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
    if (SDK_INT > 8)
    {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new 
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                .permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        //your codes here

    }
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    SQLEvent EVENTS = new SQLEvent();
    List<List<String>> EventString = EVENTS.main();
    System.out.println("EVENT RESULTS: " + EventString);
```

//////////////////SQL Event/////////////////////////

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class SQLEvent{

static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://***.***.***.***:3306/DB_NAME?useSSL=false&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC";

//  Database credentials
static final String USER = "*******";
static final String PASS = "*******";






public List <List<String>>  main() {
    ResultSet rs = null;
    Connection conn = null;
    java.sql.PreparedStatement stmt = null;
    List<List<String>> result = new ArrayList<>();

    try {
        //STEP 2: Register JDBC driver
        Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();

        //STEP 3: Open a connection
        System.out.println("Connecting to database...");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);

        //STEP 4: Execute a query
        System.out.println("Creating statement...");
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM events WHERE LOC= ?";

        stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);

        //Bind values into the parameters.
        stmt.setString(1, "matts office");  // This would set age

        // Let us update age of the record with ID = 102;
        //int rows = stmt.executeUpdate();
        //  System.out.println("Rows impacted : " + rows );

        // Let us select all the records and display them.
        // sql = "SELECT id, first, last, age FROM Employees";
        // stmt.setInt(1, 1001);
        rs = stmt.executeQuery();
        int numcols = rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount();


        //STEP 5: Extract data from result set
        while (rs.next()) {
            List<String> row = new ArrayList<>(numcols); // new list per row
            int i = 1;
            while (i <= numcols) {  // don't skip the last column, use <=
                row.add(rs.getString(i++));
            }
            result.add(row); // add it to the result

            //Retrieve by column name
            int id = rs.getInt("id");
            String LOC = rs.getString("LOC");
            String EventName = rs.getString("EventName");
            String EventDesc = rs.getString("EventDesc");
            String Closed = rs.getString("Closed");
            String TimeStart = rs.getString("TimeStart");
            String TimeEnd = rs.getString("TimeEnd");


            //Display values
            System.out.print("ID: " + id);
            System.out.print(", Location: " + LOC);
            System.out.print(", Event Name: " + EventName);
            System.out.println(", Event Description: " + EventDesc);
            System.out.println(", Closed: " + Closed);
            System.out.println(", Time Start: " + TimeStart);
            System.out.println(", Time End: " + TimeEnd);

        }
        //STEP 6: Clean-up environment
        if (!rs.next()) {

        } else {
            //  MainActivity MA = new MainActivity();
            // MA.NotificationEvent();
        }

        stmt.close();
        conn.close();
        System.out.println("Result Set: " + result);
        rs.close();




    } catch (SQLException se) {
        //Handle errors for JDBC
        se.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //Handle errors for Class.forName
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        //finally block used to close resources
        try {
            if (stmt != null)
                stmt.close();
        } catch (SQLException se2) {
        }// nothing we can do
        try {
            if (conn != null)
                conn.close();
        } catch (SQLException se) {
            se.printStackTrace();
        }//end finally try
    }//end try
    System.out.println("Goodbye!");


    return result;
}
```

}

/////////////////////ERROR LOG////////////////////////////////////////

```
07-02 18:02:43.286 11991-11991/com.internalpositioning.find3.find3app E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.internalpositioning.find3.find3app, PID: 11991
java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: Exception from call site #145 bootstrap method
    at com.mysql.cj.conf.ConnectionUrl.buildConnectionStringCacheKey(ConnectionUrl.java:236)
    at com.mysql.cj.conf.ConnectionUrl.getConnectionUrlInstance(ConnectionUrl.java:167)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:201)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:569)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:219)
    at com.internalpositioning.find3.find3app.SQLEvent.main(SQLEvent.java:45)
    at com.internalpositioning.find3.find3app.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:144)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7009)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7000)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2731)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
 Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Invalid descriptor: VIIIIIIIIII.
    at com.mysql.cj.conf.ConnectionUrl.buildConnectionStringCacheKey(ConnectionUrl.java:236) 
    at com.mysql.cj.conf.ConnectionUrl.getConnectionUrlInstance(ConnectionUrl.java:167) 
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:201) 
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:569) 
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:219) 
    at com.internalpositioning.find3.find3app.SQLEvent.main(SQLEvent.java:45) 
    at com.internalpositioning.find3.find3app.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:144) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7009) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7000) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2731) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that your version of MySQL driver does not work on the Android. It seems like, it fails on the `Collectors.joining`. This was added in Java 8.

Also, it seems to me strange to connect to database directly from Android. As far as I know, usually mobile application makes some requests (frequanlty it is REST) to the backend layer that has access to the database.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I will look into that.